# Iterate through column of dates in csv to calculate growth rate of variables every 30 days

Tags: python, loops, csv, datetime

I have a CSV file, which has a column of dates and another column for number of Twitter followers. I would like to calculate the month over month growth rate of Twitter followers, but the dates may not be an even 30 days apart. So, if I have

- 2016-03-10 with 200 followers
- 2016-02-08 with 195 followers
- 2016-01-01 with 105 followers

How can I iterate through this to generate the month over month growth rate? I've tried working with dateutil's rrule with pandas but am having difficulty. I thought about using R for this, but I'd rather do it in Python as I will output the data into a new CSV from Python.

Comment: Can you give us a sample input and a sample output (in csv format)?

Comment: `m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)` so wouldn't you just do `rate = (followers - prev_fol) / (time - prev_time)` ?  This would represent the change in followers over the change in time for any time interval

Comment: I think this really depends on what it means for there to be a "month over month" growth rate. Presumably you want the instantaneous growth rate, normalized to a what, 30 day month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team and I used the below function to solve this challenge.
The code below:

```
def compute_mom(data_list):
   list_tuple = zip(data_list[1:],data_list)
   raw_mom_growth_rate = [((float(nxt) - float(prev))/float(prev))*100 for nxt, prev in list_tuple]
   return [round(mom, 2) for mom in raw_mom_growth_rate]
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with a `defaultdict`

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

path = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\YOUR_FILE_HERE.csv"
with open(path, "r") as f:
    d = defaultdict(int)
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for dte, followers in rows:
        dte = datetime.strptime(dte, "%Y-%m-%d")
        d[dte.year, dte.month] += int(followers)
print d

to_date_followers = 0
for (year, month) in sorted(d):
    last_month_and_year = (12, year-1) if month == 1 else (month-1, year)
    old_followers = d.get(last_month_and_year, 0)
    new_followers = d[year, month]
    to_date_followers += new_followers
    print "%d followers gained in %s, %s resulting in a %.2f%% increase from %s (%s followers to date)" % (
        new_followers-old_followers, month, year, new_followers*100.0/to_date_followers, ', '.join(str(x) for x in last_month_and_year), to_date_followers
    )
```

For input below:

```
2015-12-05,10
2015-12-31,10
2016-01-01,105
2016-02-08,195
2016-03-01,200
2016-03-10,200
2017-03-01,200
```

It prints:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(2015, 12): 20, (2016, 1): 105, (2016, 3): 400, 

(2017, 3): 200, (2016, 2): 195})
20 followers gained in 12, 2015 resulting in a 100.00% increase from 11, 2015 (20 followers to date)
105 followers gained in 1, 2016 resulting in a 84.00% increase from 12, 2015 (125 followers to date)
195 followers gained in 2, 2016 resulting in a 60.94% increase from 1, 2016 (320 followers to date)
400 followers gained in 3, 2016 resulting in a 55.56% increase from 2, 2016 (720 followers to date)
200 followers gained in 3, 2017 resulting in a 21.74% increase from 2, 2017 (920 followers to date)
```

Comment: If you want a month to month comparison just play around with the month to month differences (instead of the new followers to running count ratio), the dictionary has all the data you need - how many followers do I have for a given year and month - you just need to perform your calculations based on that data

Answer (score 0):

thank you SO MUCH for replying. I was able to devise the following code, which accomplishes what I am looking for (I did not expect to be able to do this but happened to find the right functions at the right time):

```
import csv, datetime, string, os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', sep=',')
# This converts our date strings to date_time objects
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# But we only want the date, so we strip the time part
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date

sep = ' '

# This allows us to iterate through the rows in a pandas dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        start_date = df.iloc[0]['Date']
        Present = df.iloc[0]['Count']
        continue
    # This assigns the date of the row to the variable end_date
    end_date = df.iloc[index]['Date']
    delta = start_date - end_date

    # If the number of days is >= to 30
    if delta >= 30:
        print "Start Date: {}, End Date: {}, delta is {}".format(start_date, end_date, delta)
        Past = df.iloc[index]['Count']
        percent_change = ((Present-Past)/Past)*100

        df.set_value(index, 'MoM', percent_change)
        # Sets a new start date and new TW FW count
        start_date = df.iloc[index]['Date']
        Present = df.iloc[index]['Count']
```